# Can we update an existing plist file of an iphone app?

Tags: iphone

Can we update the content of an existing plist file of an iphone app such that the older plist file is replaced by the updated one in the app?

Answer (score 0):

Not without releasing a new version of the app that contains a new version of the plist file.

All the resources in an app's bundle are signed so you can't modify them. They're basically readonly.